# Formatting json data to convert to xslx

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, api

I am downloading data in json format in Python 3.7 and trying to display it as an Excel spreadsheet. I tried using pandas, but I think that there is a problem in getting the data into a dataframe. I also tried a csv approach but that was not successful.

I am new to learning python, so maybe there is something obvious I am missing.

```
import json, requests,urllib,csv
import pandas as pd
url  = urllib.request.urlopen('https://library.brown.edu/search/solr_pub/iip/?start=0&rows=100&indent=on&wt=json&q=*')
str_response = url.read().decode('utf-8')
jsondata=json.loads(str_response)
df = pd.DataFrame(jsondata)
```

I was hoping to get a number of rows for each item, e.g., zoor0353, with the columns for each of the keys associated with it (e.g., region, date_desc, etc. -there are quite a few).  Instead, it seemed only to take the first section, returning:

```
responseHeader  \
QTime                                                     1   
docs                                                    NaN   
numFound                                                NaN   
params    {'q': '*', 'indent': 'on', 'start': '0', 'rows...   
start                                                   NaN   
status                                                    0
```

```
                                                   response  
QTime                                                   NaN  
docs      [{'inscription_id': 'zoor0353', 'metadata': ['...  
numFound                                               4356  
params                                                  NaN  
start                                                     0  
status                                                  NaN
```

I tried this with normalization method, but did no better.  Ultimately, I would like to use a dataset made of an appended file of many calls to this api, and am also wondering if I will need to manipulate data, and how, to get it to work with pandas.

Comment: Did you try with [read_json](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html) method? Something like `df = pd.read_json(jsondata)`

Comment: Valentino's code gives me: ValueError: Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'dict'>

Comment: what exactly are you trying to get? for each `inscription_id`, there's 30 additional values. Do you need all of them or only some specific ones?

Comment: I would like to get it to work with all of them, for a start! I might pare down, but this I can do in Excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I'm not sure what exactly you need to get, I'll show you

1. how to use `pandas.io.json.json_normalize`
2. how to pick extract key/values

#### json_normalize

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

url = 'https://library.brown.edu/search/solr_pub/iip/?start=0&rows=100&indent=on&wt=json&q=*'
r = requests.get(url).json()
df = json_normalize(r['response']['docs']).T
```

This is a sample output; each column is a separate item of `r['response']['docs']` containing values, and rows are the keys for said values.

[image]

Data are all messed up, and also some of the keys you probably don't want to use. That's why I think it's better to extract specific keys and values.

---

```py
df = pd.DataFrame()

query = r['response']['docs']
for i in range(len(query)):
    records = [
        query[i]['inscription_id'], query[i]['city'], query[i]['_version_'],
        query[i]['type'][0], query[i]['language_display'][0], query[i]['physical_type'][0]
    ]
#     recs.append(records)

    data = pd.DataFrame.from_records([records], columns=['inscription_id', 'city', '_version_', 'type', 'language_display', 'physical_type'])
    df = df.append(data)
```

```
# sample data
    inscription_id  city    _version_   type    language_display    physical_type
0   unkn0103    Unknown 1613822149755142144 prayer  Hebrew  other_object
0   zoor0391    Zoora   1613822173978296320 funerary.epitaph    Greek   tombstone
0   zoor0369    Zoora   1613822168079007744 funerary.epitaph    Greek   tomb
0   zoor0378    Zoora   1613822170509606912 funerary.epitaph    Greek   tombstone
0   zoor0393    Zoora   1613822174648336384 funerary.epitaph    Greek   tombstone
```

## edit

> query=r[][] - what is it and how can I learn more about it?

`r = requests.get(url).json()`

by using `.json()` at the end of `requests.get` method, I converted the response object (data from the API) to a `dict` type. Hence, `r` is now a dictionary containing keys:

```
r.keys()
# dict_keys(['responseHeader', 'response'])
```

to access values of a specific key, I use a format: `dictionary[key][key_inside_of_another_key]`:

```
r['response'].keys()
# dict_keys(['numFound', 'start', 'docs'])

r['response']['docs'][0] 

# sample output
{'inscription_id': 'zoor0353',
 'metadata': ['zoor0353',
  'Negev',
  'Zoora',
  'Zoora, Negev. cemetery in An Naq. \nNegev.\n                            Zoora. Found by local inhabitants in the northwest corner of the Bronze\n                            Age, Byzantine and Islamic cemetery in the An Naq neighborhood south of\n                            the Wadi al-Hasa, probably in secondary use in later graves. \n',
  'funerary.epitaph',
...
...
...


# [0] here is an item inside of a key - in the case of your data, 
# there were 100 such items: [0, 1, .. 99] inside of r['response']['docs']
# to access item #4, you'd use ['response']['docs'][4]
```

That's how you navigate through a dictionary. Now, to access specific key, say `inscription_id` or `_version_`:

```
r['response']['docs'][0]['inscription_id']
# 'zoor0353'
r['response']['docs'][99]['inscription_id']
# 'mger0001'
r['response']['docs'][33]['_version_']
# 1613822151126679552
```

Lastly, to iterate through all rows, or items of data, I used a `for loop`: `i` here is a substitude for a range of numbers representing each item of your data -- from `r['response']['docs'][1]` to `r['response']['docs'][99]`.